# 24 VDC control using Arduino

Tags: arduino

I would like to use a Arduino as "simulator" in a training class. It would connect to an industrial controller that has 24 VDC inputs and outputs. The Arduino program would simulate the IO from a production line (sensor inputs and motor controls for example)

Is there a shield which can interface  with 24 VDC IO? I know I could use separate relays, but I want to see if there is a better solution.

I could use 12 VDC instead of 24, but nothing lower.

I am considering the Arduino as cost is factor. So I want to keep the component count and price as low as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input impedance of the PLC/controller is fairly high, you could get away with pullups and low-side transistors for inputs (to the PLC), and run outputs through a voltage divider.  Analog inputs would be a little more complex, but a basic op-amp should work fine for that unless you need high BW signals.

I don't know of a shield for this, but if you only need a couple you could get one of the stripboard/breadboard type shields and bang them out.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Arduino compatible device called a Ruggeduino designed by Rugged Circuits that can sustain +24 volts and higher.

http://ruggedcircuits.com/html/ruggeduino.html